plt.scatter でエラーが出てしまう
window.plot(model）にて描画しようとすると下記のようなエラーが発生します。
いろいろ試しましたが、解決できず質問いたしました。
何かヒントをいただけると幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします！
エラーメッセージ:
    plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\okuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\okuno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5983, in raise_from_not_ok_stat
us
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}
} Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

全体のコード:
n = len(df_4)

train = df_4[0 : int(n * 0.7)]
val = df_4[int(n * 0.7) : int(n * 0.9)]
test = df_4[int(n * 0.9) :]

print(train.shape, val.shape, test.shape)

# MinMaxScalerの処理
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train)

train_df = scaler.transform(train)
val_df = scaler.transform(val)
test_df = scaler.transform(test)

train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_df, columns=train.columns)
val_df = pd.DataFrame(val_df, columns=val.columns)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_df, columns=test.columns)

# DataWindow
class DataWindow():
    def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift, 
                 train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df, 
                 label_columns=None):
        
        self.train_df = train_df
        self.val_df = val_df
        self.test_df = test_df
        
        self.label_columns = label_columns
        if label_columns is not None:
            self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(label_columns)}
        self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(train_df.columns)}
        
        self.input_width = input_width
        self.label_width = label_width
        self.shift = shift
        
        self.total_window_size = input_width + shift
        
        self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
        self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]
        
        self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
        self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
        self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]
    
    def split_to_inputs_labels(self, features):
        inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
        labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
        if self.label_columns is not None:
            labels = tf.stack(
                [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
                axis=-1
            )
        inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
        labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None]) 
        
        return inputs, labels
    
    def plot(self, model=None, plot_col="temperature", max_subplots=1):
        inputs, labels = self.sample_batch  
        
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
        max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
        
        for n in range(max_n):
            plt.subplot(3, 1, n+1)
            plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} ')
            plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
                     label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

            if self.label_columns:
              label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
            else:
              label_col_index = plot_col_index

            if label_col_index is None:
              continue

            plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                        edgecolors='k', marker='s', label='Labels', c='green', s=64)
            if model is not None:
              predictions = model(inputs)
              plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                          marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                          c='red', s=64)

            if n == 0:
              plt.legend()

        plt.xlabel('Time(m)')
        
    def make_dataset(self, data):
        data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
        ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
            data=data,
            targets=None,
            sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
            sequence_stride=1,
            shuffle=True,
            batch_size=64
        )
        
        ds = ds.map(self.split_to_inputs_labels)
        return ds
    
    @property
    def train(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)
    
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)
    
    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)
    
    @property
    def sample_batch(self):
        result = getattr(self, '_sample_batch', None)
        if result is None:
            result = next(iter(self.train))
            self._sample_batch = result
        return result
    
    @property
    def pred(self, model=None):
        inputs, _ = self.sample_batch
        prediction = model(inputs)
        return prediction

# set window
window = DataWindow(input_width=60, label_width=60, shift=60, label_columns=["temperature"])

for example_inputs, example_labels in window.train.take(1):
  print(f'Inputs shape (batch, time, features): {example_inputs.shape}')
  print(f'Labels shape (batch, time, features): {example_labels.shape}')

# model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(60, 10))
x = layers.LSTM(35, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.LSTM(35)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1)(x) #type: ignore

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model_shape_info.png", show_shapes=True)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss="mse",
              metrics=["mae"])

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        patience = 5,
        mode = "min")
]

history = model.fit(
    window.train,
    epochs = 5,
    validation_data = window.val,
    callbacks = callbacks
)

loss, mae = model.evaluate(window.test)
print("test loss: ", loss)
print("test mae: ", mae)

loss = history.history["loss"]
val_loss = history.history["val_loss"]

# plot loss and val loss
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
ax.plot(loss, "b", label="Training loss")
ax.plot(val_loss, "r", label="Validation loss")
ax.set_xlabel("epochs")
ax.set_ylabel("loss")
ax.set_title("Training loss and Validation loss")
ax.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# plot inputs, labels, preds
window.plot(model)
print(f"prediction shape: {window.predictions_shape}")
plt.show()


「全体のコード」と書かれていますが、import等が無いのでjupyter関連の該当セルだけが提示されているものと思われます。他のセルも含めて完結したコードを提示するようにしてみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？. 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

エラーメッセージを見ると「plt.scatter でエラーが出て」いるのではなく、predictionsのスライシングにてエラーが発生しているように見受けられます。エラー発生原因を確認されると良いかと思います。また、「いろいろ試しましたが」とは具体的には何を試されてどうなったんでしょうか？回答者にとっても参考になるかと思いますので質問に追記されると良いかと思います。

検索すると似ているのがこれですが回答は何も無し。InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/ 他に似ていそうなのがこちらで参考になるかも。Problem with tf.while_loop InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/, InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 1; input has only 1 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/ #9255

皆様コメントありがとうございます！貼っていただいたURLを確認し、何とか解決できました！

解決出来ましたというコメントだけでは有効な情報にならないので、質問した内容の何処が問題であったか、どのように解決したか、どの記事が参考になったか、といったことを自己回答にしてみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。自分の質問に回答できますか？

@kunif 作法が分かっておらず申し訳ございません。

参考になったURLはProblem with tf.while_loop InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/です。
問題はPredictionの次元とplt.scatterで描画できる次元が違ったので、predictionの次元を2次元に変更することにより描画できるようになりました。
ご助言ありがとうございます。
